# How to access private property through App Component in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am getting the current url through the code i declared in app component to my app.component.html

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  public href: string = "";

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="page-wrap {{router.url}}">

  <app-header></app-header>

  <div class="content-wrap">

    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>

    <div class="app-content">
      <flash-messages></flash-messages>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

When I compile the code above through "ng serve -prod", i am prompted with:

> ERROR in C:/Users/theone/Documents/Node Projects
>   SourceTree/dream-angular/src/$$_gendir/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts
>   (58,68): Property 'router' is private and only accessible within class
>   'AppComponent'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong. The field is private. It cannot be accessed from the template. Try

```
constructor(public router: Router) { }
```

Comment: Posting the same answer again :)

Comment: actually i posted the same before you did. it just that you did not read the 2nd line as i mentioned. then i edited with the code!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
ng build --env=prod 
Seems ng build --env=prod and ng build --prod are not same.
```

and its a known issue with angular-cli if you are using old versions. or you need to change it to public

```
constructor(public router: Router) { }
```

Here is the mentioned issue :  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5621